# How do I define and typedef a struct containing a pointer to itself?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have two files (.h and .c for each of them). I am defining the following struct inside one of the header files:

```
 typedef struct Client{
    int fd;
    struct in_addr ipaddr;
    struct Player * p;
    struct Client * next;
 }Client;
```

I've tried a number of different suggested combinations of typedef and struct but I'm still getting `error: redefinition of ‘struct client’`

I'm starting to think this has to do with the fact both header files include each-other.

Am I creating this struct correctly? Is there some fundamental rules I should be following when including header files in each-other?

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to having a struct containing a pointer to itself.

Comment: The problem with this question is that the code you posted doesn't generate that error. A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: My best guess is that what you're looking for is [header guards](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/447/preprocessor-and-macros/7662/header-include-guards#t=201608020345015731289)

Comment: The code you have shown us [is correct](http://ideone.com/FvTqSv). Therefore the problem lies somewhere in the code you haven't shown us. Please reduce your program to the smallest complete program that actually demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two structs that depend on each other, you can forward declare one of them.

```
typedef struct Client Client;   // forward declaration of struct Client

typedef struct Player {
    ...
    Client *client;
    ...
} Player;

struct Client{
    int fd;
    struct in_addr ipaddr;
    Player * p;
    Client * next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`typedef struct x3 { ... } x3;`

It's legal, if potentially obscure, to use the same name for both the tag and the typedef, since they live in separate namespaces.

http://c-faq.com/struct/typedef.html